# JQuery wrap() function only correctly wraps links around image first time through a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is simply supposed to loop through a list of artists generating an image and a link for each item.  This works the first time through the loop, however for subsequent iterations the `wrap()` link around the image doesn't seem to be added.  I've tried a few various ways, including having all the code to be wrapped in a separate variable and the best I've got is that the link will be generated, but not actually wrapped around the `thumb` class (*).  I'm afraid client-side goings-on aren't my strong point so I'm struggling to see why only the first iteration of the loop is successfully wrapped in a link.

*That was using dynamically-generated attribute IDs and wrapping that instead of using the class attribute as follows.

```
function showArtists(adata) {
    $("#artists").html("");

    for (var i = 0; i < adata.artists.length; i++) {

        var artist = adata.artists[i];

        var artistSpan = document.createElement("span");
        artistSpan.setAttribute("class", "artistView");

        var artistPic = document.createElement("img");
        artistPic.setAttribute("class","thumb");
        artistPic.setAttribute("src",artistPicture)

        $('.thumb').wrap(function() {return "<a href='#' onclick ='getAlbums(artist)'> </a>"});         

        artistSpan.appendChild(artistPic);

        $("#artists").append(artistSpan);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is `artistPicture` defined?

Comment: Apologies - trying to keep code to a minimum.  It comes as JSON data alongside artist and others.  Anyway, that all works fine.

Comment: I don't understand your note, "*That was using dynamically-generated IDs and wrapping that instead of using the class attribute as follows." Are you using `.wrap()` by targeting a class or an ID? It also would be helpful if you posted your HTML.

Comment: That's fine.  Since you're using jQuery, I'd avoid creating elements in JavaScript and instead use a solution like @Judson posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using jQuery .each? Or jQuery .map?

http://jsfiddle.net/m4k5o992/2/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    showArtists();

});
function showArtists() {


    var artists = [

      { 

            id : "1",
            artistThumb: "http://placehold.it/350x150",
            name : "Van Gogh"

        },

  {

            id : "2",
            artistThumb: "http://placehold.it/350x150",
            name : "Some Dude"           

        }   

    ]





    $("#artists").html("");


    $.each(artists, function(index, i){
        console.log(index, i);
        $("#artists").append('<li><a href="#" onclick ="getAlbums(' + i.id + ')"> <span class="artistView">'+ i.name +' </span><img class="thumb" src=' +  i.artistThumb + '"/></a></li>');


    });



}
```

Comment: No, but I will give it a go - is there any specific reason that you know of that the above fails to work?  Just out of curiosity?

Comment: I edited my answer to help you. I just created an arrray based on what you provided. You should be able to take what I did and work your magic. Let me know if you need any further assistance.